# Second conditional and sequence of tenses

Tags: conditional-constructions, subject-verb-agreement, tense-agreement

Should I use past tense in such sentences? Which one is correct?

> If I said I **was** going to Canada, would you accompany me?
>   If I said I **am** going to Canada, would you accompany me?

Answer (score 1):

There is near-universal agreement that, in most examples of what is sometimes called the "second conditional", we should use the *simple past* after *if,* followed by the hypothetical consequence of the *if* condition which is expressed in a clause using the auxiliary verb *would.*

However, note that here, it is not the forms of the verb *be* (which are in bold text in your question) that should be in the simple past; rather, it is the form of the verb *say.*

Therefore, since *say* is in the simple past in both examples, both are proper "second conditional" sentences. (However, the second example would almost never be heard from a native speaker.)

To express your second example as a *first conditional,* both verbs would have to be in the *simple present:*

> If I **say** I am going to Canada, **will** you accompany me?

Wikipedia includes a useful discussion of the *[second conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional).*

Comment: To sum up: does it mean that **if I said I am** is not idiomatic and **if I said I was** should be preferred, provided the situation is hypothetical and unlikely?

Comment: Yeah, the meat of what you're expounding isn't about what the inquirer, well, inquired. Would you mind addressing the actual issue by perhaps supplying contexts in which each of those sentences would sound natural? (*Almost never* suggests this possibility exists.)

Comment: @olegst Idiomatically, _if I said I was_ is probably best. N.B.: In your examples, the tense of the copula is not germane to the conditionality of the sentence.

Comment: "the tense of the copula is not germane " - how do you mean? In both?

Comment: The copula in your sentences has no relationship to the conditionality of the sentences. In the sentence _"If I said I am going to Canada, would you accompany me?"_ it is the tense of the verb _say_ that is germane, not the tense of the copula _be_. Both sentences are valid "second conditional" sentences.